# If $\lim_{x \to a^+} {1 \over f(x)} = 0$, then $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \infty$

Tags: limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Suppose $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ where $I$ is an open interval (say $(a,b)$). Also assume that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$.  Then

If  $\lim_{x \to a^+} {1 \over f(x)} = 0$, then  $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \infty$

Note that $a^+$ is the limit from the right.

Here is my go. Does it look correct? I am told that I should pick an arbitrary $N$ at the beginning of the proof but did not understand what that means.

**Proof**

Suppose $f : (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x \to a^+} {1 \over f(x)} = 0.$ By definition, this means $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists m\in(a,b)$ such that if $a < x < m$, then $|1/f(x) - 0|< \epsilon$.

With $\epsilon>0$, we have $1/f(x) < \epsilon$ whenever $a < x < m$. This implies that if $a < x < m$ then $ f(x) > 1/ \epsilon >0$. It follows that we can find some $N = 1/\epsilon> 0$ such that $f(x) >N$ whenever $a < x < m$. This completes the proof that $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \infty $}

Comment: The last line is the wrong conclusion : for each $N$ you need an $m$. You start with $N$, take $\epsilon  = \frac 1N$ and put it in the second to last statement and then you are done.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome! But how will you close this question? Write an answer and accept it yourself, maybe using my comment.